# WinDbg not showing entire call stack?

Tags: windows, debugging, windbg, callstack

I am trying to debug a very old game called "Ballmaster" (whose source code I do not possess) using WinDbg. I attached WinDbg to the game when a dialog is shown so that the call stack of the UI thread does not change.

Here is a list of the running threads:

[image: Thread View]

When I click on the `Ballmaster` thread, the following call stack is presented:

```
ntdll!NtDelayExecution + 0xc
KERNELBASE!SleepEx + 0x99
KERNELBASE!Sleep + 0xf
USER31!HookedCreateWindowExA + 0x41
DlgBox!Ordinal49 + 0x35dd
DlgBox!Ordinal49 + 0x4d58
uxtheme!ThemePreDefDlgProc + 0x83
USER32!UserCallDlgProcCheckWow + 0x2a8
USER32!DefDlgProcWorker + 0xc7
USER32!DefDlgProcA + 0x25
USER32!_InternalCallWinProc + 0x2b
USER32!UserCallWinProcCheckWow + 0x2d3
USER32!SendMessageWorker + 0x26c
USER32!InternalCreateDialog + 0xb07
USER32!CreateDialogIndirectParamAorW + 0x35
USER32!CreateDialogIndirectParamA + 0x1b
DlgBox!Ordinal49 + 0x52bf
```

`Ballmaster` is the main UI thread, and it is freezed at dialog creation. However, the bottom-most function that is recorded in the call stack is `DlgBox!Ordinal49`, which is found in `DlgBox.dll`, which is loaded by the executable.

Obviously that is not the complete call stack, as due to the fact that that is the main thread, the `main()` method in the executable could not have exited/returned as otherwise the process would close.

Then why does the call stack end with a function in a DLL instead of a function in the main executable? **How do I view the full call stack?**

`!address DlgBox!Ordinal49+0x52bf` presents the following:

```
Usage:                  Image
Base Address:           028e1000
End Address:            028f2000
Region Size:            00011000 (  68.000 kB)
State:                  00001000          MEM_COMMIT
Protect:                00000020          PAGE_EXECUTE_READ
Type:                   01000000          MEM_IMAGE
Allocation Base:        028e0000
Allocation Protect:     00000080          PAGE_EXECUTE_WRITECOPY
Image Path:             C:\Users\mathu\Desktop\Games\Ballmaster\CrtC0B.tmp\DlgBox.DLL
Module Name:            DlgBox
Loaded Image Name:      C:\Users\mathu\Desktop\Games\Ballmaster\CrtC0B.tmp\DlgBox.DLL
Mapped Image Name:      
More info:              lmv m DlgBox
More info:              !lmi DlgBox
More info:              ln 0x28e52bf
More info:              !dh 0x28e0000
```

Comment: but if *pdb* files (with frame information) not available for all modules in stack - in x86 impossible always get full stack trace. debugger assume that function used *ebp* frame (`push ebp;mov ebp,esp` at begin) and walk by this *ebp* chain. but if some function not used this frame - here stack trace can stop.

Comment: Ah, so is there a way to try out different frame types?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.kframes <FrameCountDefault>`:

> The .kframes command sets the default length of a stack trace display.
>
> [...]
>
> If you never issue the .kframes command, the default count is 20 (0x14).

If you use the `k` command, you can also specify a length, e.g. `k Lfff`